# How to convert php string to json by id?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a button that will bring me to `endDate.php` to update the database and return a text of true or false of this progress. I'm not familiar with JSON and JavaScript so this is the best of me to combine the php and JavaScript code.

So the problem now is when i click on the button, on my page it does show that the value is true or false from the `php`, but when i needed the alert pop up message, it shows that `Type error: Unable to get the property of 'value' of undefined or null references`.
How can i convert the datatype from php to json so it can use for my condition statement in `JavaScript`?

**task.php**

part that receive the `value` to be true or false

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['value'])){

    echo "<p name='va' id='va' >".$_SESSION['value']."</p>";
  };
    session_destroy();
?>
```

Button to end the task, and error message to check whether the progess is already ended by getting the value in the text.

```
<?php

              echo "<tr>
              <td>
              <button onclick='endProcess(".$row->task_id.")' type='submit'  name='end' id='end'>END</button>
              </td>
              </tr>";
            }
            $conn->close();
        ?>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        function endProcess(task_id){
          var myObj;
          myObj = task_id;
          var myJSON = JSON.stringify(myObj);
          window.location = "endDate.php?x=" + myJSON;

          try{
            var jobValue = document.getElementById('va').value;

            if (jobValue === "false") throw "has not yet started!";
            if (jobValue === "true") throw "has closed.";

          }
          catch(err){
            alert("The task " + err)
          }
        }

        </script>
```

**endDate.php**

```
    session_start();


    $_SESSION['value'] = 'true';

    header('location:'. $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    exit();
    }
```

Comment: This code is confusing. Which line exactly causes the error? Also, `window.location` will cause your page to redirect to `endDate.php` before it ever executes the contents of your `try` block, so it's not clear what you were trying to do there. And you have a `<script>` tag missing. And you are including jQuery but not using it for anything.

Comment: It's also not clear why you are using `JSON.stringify` - you're trying to stringify myObj which was originally task_id. And judging by `endProcess(".$row->task_id.")`, I woudl expect task_id would be a simple integer, not a complex object or array, so stringifying it to JSON won't achieve anything useful.

Comment: I use `window.location` cause I can't put php function inside the javascript, so I use it to bring the `task_id` to `endDate.php` to do sql query. This part has no error. 

I uses JSON.stringify cause the code show nothing when I use pure myObj. 

My problem is how my `var jobValue = document.getElementById('va').value;` can get the right datatype to be display in `if (jobValue === "false") throw "has not yet started!";` @ADyson

Comment: That bit `var jobValue = ...etc` will never execute though, that was my point. After the `window.location` command, your JS code will stop executing because the browser will go to another page.

Comment: "I uses JSON.stringify cause the code show nothing when I use pure myObj"...this seems very unlikely but ok, whatever. I'm 99.9% sure it's redundant.

Comment: @ADyson is there any other way that I can use with onclick and send the task_id  to another php file function?

Comment: and about the `window.location` so I should make the try and catch into another function or how?

Comment: I tried to use $.ajax and stuff but the miscrosoft edge keep saying "object doesn't support property or method 'ajax' microsoft edge"

Comment: "I tried to use $.ajax"...that requires jQuery. It looks like you added jQuery to your page, so presumably you've used it incorrectly. Hard to know how exactly, without seeing code. But there are 1000s of examples online, it should not be hard to copy one of those. Of course $.ajax isn't the only way to send an AJAX request. `fetch()` is built into all modern browsers, without needing to add any dependencies. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using AJAX might be more efficient in this case, there's nothing wrong in theory with the way you're sending the data now.

The problem seems to be with how you're trying to deal with it when you're redirected back to task.php.

Your `try` block is inside a function which only runs when the button is clicked, and it occurs after a `window.location` command, meaning it will never be executed in any circumstances.

But it seems to me you would want that bit of code to run when your page first loads, so it can check the value every time. So I think really it shouldn't be inside any function at all.

Try it like this:

```
function endProcess(task_id) {
  var myObj;
  myObj = task_id;
  var myJSON = JSON.stringify(myObj);
  window.location = "endDate.php?x=" + myJSON;
}

try {
  var jobValue = document.getElementById('va').value;

  if (jobValue === "false") throw "has not yet started!";
  if (jobValue === "true") throw "has closed.";
}
catch(err) {
  alert("The task " + err)
}
```

P.S. I'm 99.9% sure you don't need JSON here. Your `endProcess` function is being passed a task ID which, from your PHP code, I strongly suspect is either a number or a simple string. So it should be sufficient for the function to look like this:

```
function endProcess(task_id) {
  window.location = "endDate.php?x=" + task_id;
}
```

P.P.S. Try/catch is not really an appropriate mechanism for simply testing a value - it's intended for catching exceptions in the code, not making decisions about what message to display. Just the simple `if` statements and a status string would be more appropriate:

```
var jobValue = document.getElementById('va').value;
var status = "The task ";    
if (jobValue === "false") status += "has not yet started!";
else if (jobValue === "true") status += "has closed.";
alert(status);
```